# How do I keep just the last 5 versions of build jars?

Tags: ant, build.xml

When I run an Ant build I want to keep just the last 5 build jars and remove all others. Please see major and minor version of below file.

Suppose I have these previously built jars in my build directory:

```
test-1.0.0.jar 
test-1.0.1.jar 
test-1.0.2.jar 
test-1.0.3.jar 
test-1.0.4.jar 
test-1.0.5.jar 
test-1.0.6.jar
```

When I run the next build, the effect should be like this:

```
test-1.0.0.jar -- Deleted
test-1.0.1.jar -- Deleted
test-1.0.2.jar -- Deleted

test-1.0.3.jar -- No change
test-1.0.4.jar -- No change 
test-1.0.5.jar -- No change 
test-1.0.6.jar -- No change
test-1.0.7.jar -- No change
```

That means I want to keep only latest 5 builds (based on minor version) and remove all others.

Please note here latest is determined based on build jar minor version.

Can this be done using an Ant buildfile?

Answer (score 1):

The following will delete old files, keeping the most recent 5:

```
<delete>
  <allbutlast count="5">
    <sort>
      <date/>
      <fileset dir="target" includes="*.jar"/>
    </sort>
  </allbutlast>
</delete>
```

---

A more complete solution would be to publish artifacts into a dedicated repository manager, rather than building your own.

For example if you choose to use [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), it has a scheduled task called "Remove Releases From Repository" that will delete old releases based on semantic versioning rules:

- https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/scheduled-tasks.html

Comment: Thanks @mark O'Connor  for your answer.
I want to sort files by filename rather than date.
For e.g.test-1.0.0.jar && test-1.0.1.jar 
test-1.0.0.jar is old and test-1.0.1.jar is new

Comment: In addition to this answer, if you want to make last build count configurable then you can also specify count value in properties file and import properties file in your build file.

Comment: @Maverick ANT is a build tool. I highly recommend using a repository manager product like Nexus to manage the archiving rules for release artifacts. If you follow the link about you'll discover Nexus already has features for deleting files based on the release number. This I think will meet your requirement.